# What should the schedule to our blog be?

Tags: discussion, community-blog

Should the schedule be a post gets published once a week? where people can read weekly, or should it be once every two weeks? where a post can have more time to be read until the next, and hopefully wouldn't be too hard on the contributors. What do you think? Of course as we have mentioned, each contributor can right on their own time, whether it is once a week or once a month.  As it is suggested [here](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/), we each should have some posts in our pockets so that if we don't get to writing a new post we can use that which we have.

Furthermore, from a post from a moderator from programmers.SE, it is suggested that we have some posts pre-written ready to get published once we get our blog.  I have completed two posts ready to get published when we get a blog, both are in regards to uloom-Al Quran.  So if we choose to have our schedule to be a post gets published once a week than we have enough posts to successfully go through the first two weeks of our blog Insha'Allah, and if we choose once every two weeks, then we have enough posts to successfully go through one month of the blog Insha'Allah.

---

As a side note: I have also spoken to one of the C.SE moderators in regards to their blog, and he said that they chose what their topics will be for like the first month and then lined up the writers.  Also we should sort out who will be the writers, who will be the editors, and who will be those who will be holding the reins managing all this.  Furthermore we need a good/excellent/meaningful/appropriate/Islamic name for our blog.

Comment: The way the Christianity blog works is, I think, unique to that site. It's a *good* format (four different writers writing from different perspectives about the same subject), but it's not the *only* format. It's a format you might try for a month or two, and then try something else. (C.SE have changed it occasionally too: they did "personal testimony" for two months.)

Comment: @TRiG interesting, they have told me that it is in a kind of a debate format (not quite) but similar.

Comment: As an example, see the series on [Church and State](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/2012/11/05/church-and-state-separate-or-same/): one introductory post, then four from different writers from different backgrounds. That's the standard format. On the other hand, sudden news like [the resignation of a Pope](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/2013/02/12/12%CF%86-pope-declaratio-et-resignatio/) went up as its own post, not part of a series. And the [recent post on Easter](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/2013/03/31/easter-what-jesus-resurrection-means-for-us/) went up without an intro.